# Unable to pass a parameter through <s:a> in DisplayTag

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

```
<display:column title="Edit Here">
   <s:url id="url1" action="editAction">
   <s:param name="id">
      <s:property value="news.id" />
   </s:param>
   </s:url>
   <s:a href="%{url1}">Edit</s:a>
</display:column>
```

id is property in my action class,zero is being passed everytime rather than the corresponding id of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<s:param name="id">
    <s:property value="news.id" />
</s:param>
```

to this:

```
<s:param name="id" value="#attr.news.id"></s:param>
```

It should be enough.

`#attr` is the OGNL used to access the pageContext (then request, session and application scopes).